# ScrollView in Kivy not working properly, rebounding on each scroll down and finally bouncing back all the way to the top page

Tags: kivy, scrollview

ScrollView in Kivy not working properly, rebounding on each scroll down and finally bouncing back all the way to the to the top page. How to make it stable(KivyMD on windows 10)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.font_definitions import theme_font_styles


KV = '''
Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            title: "MDLabel"

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                GridLayout:
                    id: box
                    cols:1
                    spacing:100
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        creen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        # Names of standard font styles.
        for name_style in theme_font_styles[:-1]:
            for i in range(0, 10):
                creen.ids.box.add_widget(
                    MDLabel(
                        size=creen.ids.box.size,
                        text=f"{name_style} style",
                        halign="center",
                        font_style=name_style,
                    )
                )
        return creen


Test().run()
```

Comment: Got to know that it is a problem in kivy 2.0.0 on many windows devices, https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/8d515b873778d080f8b9947671016724a88a5009#diff-76dea3a7b43294a74db9d92fbcd285f4a60630bac37559320de399d1f820baf2 applied the fix now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
```

to your `GridLayout`.

Comment: It is not rebounding on scroll down and now i can go to the last page, thanks a lot.  However when scrolling up there is a little rebound on each scroll up action, and i am facing this issue in all the files with  ScrollView class  , can you please suggest a remedy.

Comment: Hey, I would like to update my query; slow scroll up or down results in scrolling up, fast scrolling down working as expected whereas fast scroll up results in scroll up with continuous continuous rebound.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you describe, but try adding `effect_cls: ScrollEffect` to your `ScrollView` rule. That will require adding `#:import ScrollEffect  kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect` to your `KV` string.

Comment: Got to know that it is a problem in kivy 2.0.0 on many windows devices, https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/8d515b873778d080f8b9947671016724a88a5009#diff-76dea3a7b43294a74db9d92fbcd285f4a60630bac37559320de399d1f820baf2 applied the fix now it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your response.